# Images with Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, background, python-imaging-library

I am having quite some problems trying to implement images in my game. I want to put each image in the frames I created for the different stages of the game, however, this seems impossible. I can only get it to work if I place the image in the window (and thus I can't change the background). What would be the best way to do this?

Also, the image dimensions are the same as the ones for the window I created. However, how do I make it so the image fits the whole screen instead of just a small part in the middle? (attaching image and code for reference)

Issues are only in the functions setting_up_bg and setting_up_bg_2 I think (the second one is meant for the second background but it's not working)

[image]

```py
class Main_Menu():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.state('zoomed')
        self.main_menu_frame = Frame(self.window, width=800, height=600)   #try to put background here in this frame
        self.configure_window()
        self.create_menu()

    def setting_up_bg(self):
        # self.background = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\acout\OneDrive - Activos Reais\Uni\Git\Tkinter\race_track.png')
        # self.background_label = Label(self.window, image=self.background)
        # self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        # self.background_label.tkimg = self.background
        self.background = Image.open(r"C:\Users\acout\OneDrive - Activos Reais\Uni\Git\Tkinter\race_game_bg.png")
        test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.background)
        label1 = Label(image=test)
        label1.image = test
        label1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)



    def setting_up_bg_2(self):
        self.background_2_frame = Frame(self.window, bg='white')
        self.background_2_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.background_2 = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\acout\OneDrive - Activos Reais\Uni\Git\Tkinter\race_game_bg.png')
        
        self.background_2_label = Label(self.background_2_frame, image=self.background_2)
        self.background_2_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.background_label.tkimg = self.background_2



    def configure_window(self):
        self.window.geometry("800x600")
        self.window.configure(background='#b3ffff')
        self.window.title("My Tkinter game yo - car go brrr")
        self.window.iconbitmap(default=r'C:\Users\acout\OneDrive - Activos Reais\Uni\Git\Tkinter\carro.ico')

        # setting up grid
        self.window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.window.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.window.rowconfigure(0, weight=7)
        self.window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.window.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.window.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.window.rowconfigure(5, weight=5)

        self.setting_up_bg()
```

Comment: do you just want to resize [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177969/how-to-resize-an-image-using-tkinter) or are you looking for a the image till fill all the space?

Comment: also it helps if you make a minimal amount of code. so trim away all the bits that aren't relevant to the question

Comment: @ellieff1493 i want the image to fill all the space, i guess i can zoom but this would be annoying. this problem didn't happen with the other imaged i tried implementing so idk. ps: i realised i forgot to put the image so i am attaching it to the question :)

Comment: @ellieff1493 trimmed it :)

Comment: @ellieff1493 zooming with (2,2) is too much and there's no way to input non-integer values, how do i do this?

Comment: @ellieff1493 my image is 800x600 and so is my window but it keeps showing up like that. how can i fix this? pls help me im panicking